# Laravel Criar Chave composta para tabela pivo?

Tags: laravel, chave-composta, model-validation

Gostaria de saber como é possível realizar validação no laravel 6.x para chaves compostas ?

Estou querendo inserir novos dados uma tabela pivo que tem ligação muitos para muitos com outras duas tabelas.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('acl_cm_tecnicos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_tecnicos');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_cms');
        $table->primary(['id_tecnicos', 'id_cms']);
        $table->foreign('id_tecnicos')->references('id')->on('ctrl_lista_tecnicos');
        $table->foreign('id_cms')->references('id')->on('ctrl_cm_tecnicos');
    });
}
```

Realizei testes para inserção de novos dados estão ok !

Porem gostaria de ter uma validação no `backend`, para não dar erro na aplicação em casos de tentarem inserir registros duplicados.

Tentei criar algumas validações como esta.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    //$cadAcl = $this->objAcl->create([
    //    'id_tecnicos'=>$request->id_tecnico,
    //    'id_cms'=>$request->id_cm,
    //]);

    $datatec = $this -> $request->tecnico_id;
    $datacm = $this -> $request->id_cms;

       $validacao =  $this->validate($request, [
            'id_tecnicos' => 'unique:acl_cm_tecnicos,id_tecnicos,NULL,id,id_cms'.$datacm,
            'id_cms' => 'unique:acl_cm_tecnicos,id_cms,NULL,id,id_tecnicos'.$datatec,
            
        ]
        );

        dd($validacao);
```

Porem confesso que estou meio perdido pelas tentativas que já realizei.
Nesta ultima tentativa estou com seguinte erro na saída do dd($validacao);

> ErrorException Undefined property:
> App\Http\Controllers\Agendamento\Recurso\AclTecnicosController::$POST
> /acltecnicos HTTP/1.1  Accept:
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br  Accept-Language:
> en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7  Cache-Control: max-age=0
> Connection: keep-alive  Content-Length: 372  Content-Type:
> multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydPBr1IkfB0nTX9du
> Cookie:
> XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkJQd1p1bjRmelBkZG03bVwvU3pwZ1R3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InJiMlZFaUg5OVwvR1E0Y2lxVlwvOUtnaklVMWQ2c3lcL1B0SFwveUlWczQ4K3VaQlhOVldQUitlT000VEw5MFE2YklmRmJmUjA0MDFMMmNtTTJWcmNYcndNZGR4N3BWMGNzcU5ndG5USTJXMzdqdDI2cEFRNTNUcG5cL1BKRktVS2F5dzUiLCJtYWMiOiJhZjQ1ZWIwNzYxZDU1MGE5MTg2MjNlNjM0Zjk4NjM1Nzg0OTQ2NTA1YTU0NTA0ZGRkNzA1ZjFhMDU1MGE1NTJmIn0%3D;
> laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjUrb3EzK3hBd3ZXSEtRTTFFVGswZUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidjNSQ3pIM0ZOSytqMWlPZWEwS1N6VmlBZ2VRT21DRHlBNHRlOTk5cDRQaGtpTjN3bnZ5V2djeXBhb0F1WmJzVDliWncybXFOWnRqTkJcL1g2UHVMNVIyODk2aVlkdlBIdTdoQzJtbmFya3ZQd3pxQngxUTA4K3p4ZUhmMkNwR3dxIiwibWFjIjoiZDliNGJlNzQ5MmZhMWU1ODY3ZjcyYjk2ZTg1NmEyZDgxOGJjNmZjMWNhYzcxMzI2MzgyNzdjYzgwY2UyZTU4YiJ9
> Dnt: 1  Host: 127.0.0.1:8000  Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000  Referer:
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/tecnicos/980/edit  Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
> Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate  Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin  Sec-Fetch-User:
> ?1  Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36  Cookie:
> XSRF-TOKEN=JPFBbalPGyX59xVGTDrSGcsHYYFSbaQEUIK8gjts;
> laravel_session=zY4ITpf8RvqzZ55HJMwlKOra8QuErGbPExGDel5S

Answer (score 0):

Precisa criar um regra para essa tabela com o comando:

```
php > php artisan make:rule TestRule
```

após dar esse comando o código é criado em: `app\Rules`, abra o arquivo e comece a sua codificação:

```
<?php namespace App\Rules;

use App\Test;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestRule implements Rule
{
    public $request;
    public $test;
    public function __construct(Request $request, Test $test)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $p1 = $this->request->input('p1');
        $p2 = $this->request->input('p2');
        $count = $this->test->where(function($query) use($p1,$p2) {
            $query->where('p1', $p1)
                ->where('p2', $p2);
        })
        ->count();
        return (int)$count === 0;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The duplicate value';
    }
}
```

que no seu construtor passe o `Request` e a classe responsável por essa tabela no caso exemplo desse código é `Test`.

Dentro do método `passes($attribute, $value)` tem um código que busca se o dado da requisição pode estar duplicado e no método `count` da `builder` é contado se existe algum item nessa pesquisa.

No código que chega a requisição coloque essa regra na parte de validação:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'p1' => ['required', new TestRule($request, $this->model)], // regra
    'p2' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('test')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
} else {
    $this->model->create($request->except('_token'));
    return redirect('test');
}
```

basicamente, crie um regra com o comando mencionado, implementa um código de verificação na tabela pelo método `passes` e no código do botão de requisição instancie a classe de regras e passe o valor de seu construtor.

Comment: Muito Obrigado deu certo vlw pela força !!!